# exporting data from excel to MS Sql 

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, excel, vba

I have saved the specifications of a mobile phone into an Excel spreadsheet. Now I want to copy the data from this Excel sheet into a database programmatically.

How can I do this? Is there any way? I copied the phone specs from gsmarena.com. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's completely possible. There are several ways, not all of which require programming.

If the Excel sheet is in a tabular format (one "record" per row, with static column names), you may be able to use your database management tool (MS Sql Management Studio for Sql Server, for instance) to do a "bulk insert". Consult the documentation for your particular database.

You can also use Excel formulas to create a column in the Excel sheet that contains "Insert" statements that will insert each row into the DB. You simply copy that column out of the sheet and paste it into a SQL command parser, maybe wrap it in a transaction, and then hit "execute". I've done this a few times when doing data migration; it's kind of a one-off, but for a one-time operation that's just fine.

If you want to use a program to solve the problem, you'll need to use OLE automation to open your Excel sheet, and programatically iterate over the rows and columns to create a "record" that you save to the database. The exact wheres and hows are a little in-depth, and depend a lot on the type of database, your version of Excel, the type of Excel document you have (XLS or XLSX), and how your Excel sheet is organized.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool such as [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx), or connect via ADO.Net and OleDb/Jet drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, is the database properly designed and ready to go?  If not, you need to first design one, which I suggest you base on normalizing the Excel data.  Once that's complete, you can use the interop libraries for .NET to pull the data from Excel and write to the DB through MySQL, Access or some other DBMS.

Comment: Ya the DB i properly designed and ready to go....could you please direct me to any tutorial relating to interop libraries??